# while running mvn jetty:run showing the following error 

Tags: maven-2, appfuse

```
C:\source\myproject>mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AppFuse Spring MVC Application
[INFO]    task-segment: [jetty:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing jetty:run
[WARNING] POM for 'xfire:xfire-jsr181-api:pom:1.0-M1:compile' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] [warpath:add-classes {execution: default}]
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [native2ascii:native2ascii {execution: native2ascii-utf8}]
[INFO] [native2ascii:native2ascii {execution: native2ascii-8859_1}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] Preparing hibernate3:hbm2ddl
[WARNING] Removing: hbm2ddl from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[INFO] [warpath:add-classes {execution: default}]
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [native2ascii:native2ascii {execution: native2ascii-utf8}]
[INFO] [native2ascii:native2ascii {execution: native2ascii-8859_1}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] [hibernate3:hbm2ddl {execution: default}]
[INFO] Configuration XML file loaded: file:/C:/source/myproject/src/main/resourc
es/hibernate.cfg.xml
[INFO] Configuration XML file loaded: file:/C:/source/myproject/src/main/resourc
es/hibernate.cfg.xml
[INFO] Configuration Properties file loaded: C:\source\myproject\target\classes\
jdbc.properties
alter table user_role drop foreign key FK143BF46A4FD90D75;
alter table user_role drop foreign key FK143BF46AF503D155;
drop table if exists app_user;
drop table if exists role;
drop table if exists user_role;
create table app_user (id bigint not null auto_increment, account_expired bit no
t null, account_locked bit not null, address varchar(150), city varchar(50) not
null, country varchar(100), postal_code varchar(15) not null, province varchar(1
00), credentials_expired bit not null, email varchar(255) not null unique, accou
nt_enabled bit, first_name varchar(50) not null, last_name varchar(50) not null,
 password varchar(255) not null, password_hint varchar(255), phone_number varcha
r(255), username varchar(50) not null unique, version integer, website varchar(2
55), primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create table role (id bigint not null auto_increment, description varchar(64), n
ame varchar(20), primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create table user_role (user_id bigint not null, role_id bigint not null, primar
y key (user_id, role_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table user_role add index FK143BF46A4FD90D75 (role_id), add constraint FK1
43BF46A4FD90D75 foreign key (role_id) references role (id);
alter table user_role add index FK143BF46AF503D155 (user_id), add constraint FK1
43BF46AF503D155 foreign key (user_id) references app_user (id);
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [dbunit:operation {execution: test-compile}]
[INFO] [jetty:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: AppFuse Spring MVC Application
[INFO] Webapp source directory = C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp
[INFO] web.xml file = C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
[INFO] Classes = C:\source\myproject\target\classes
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\applicationContext-validation.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\dispatcher-servlet.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\menu-config.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\urlrewrite.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\validation.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\validator-rules-custom.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\validator-rules.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
2010-06-02 15:13:28.921::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.9 ...
2010-06-02 15:13:28.983::INFO:  jetty-6.1.9
2010-06-02 15:13:28.248::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2010-06-02 15:13:28.482:/:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[myproject] ERROR [main] ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(215) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:293)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        ... 51 more
2010-06-02 15:13:29.919::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@1ba4806{/,C:\source\myproject\src\main\webapp}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:293)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        ... 51 more
2010-06-02 15:13:29.152::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xfire-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:293)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
2010-06-02 15:13:29.417::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 3 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search suggests you need to use `mvn jetty:run-war` not `mvn jetty:run`.

If you want it to extract the files instead you can do `mvn war:inplace`.